# How to unsubscribe from messaging center when using the ON SCREEN back button on android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to unsubscribe from the messaging center when the user uses the back button (top left) on a certain page. I am already doing it for the hardware back button

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {

            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<App, string>(this, "Trolley");
            return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
        }
```

But it does not work for the back button showing on screen.
I am aware of the existence of "OnDisappearing" but it does not work in my case because I actually need it to work when entering a new page.

I am on Page 1 and subscribe to "Trolley" then I load page 2, send a message "Trolley" and finally close page 2. OnDisappearing triggers when I load page 2 so I wouldn't be able to receive the message if I where to unsubscribe in OnDisappearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to understand about [Xamarin Life Cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle). And by overriding `OnBackButtonPressed()` **will only work** when you tap physical back button (near Home button) on `Android` devices **only**.

For your case, I think you need to use `PageAppearing` to subscribe and use `PageDisappearing` when you want to unsubscribe.

There is no `OnPushed` or `OnPopped` for non modal page. If you wish a method like that you need to customize your logic.

## EDIT

i found an example of a way to do this https://gist.github.com/housecode/33c11faecff2d7be39f3b7503a686527

#### Here the code from the gist

Extending `Xamarin.Forms` `NavigationPage` to add `OnPushed` and `OnPopped` event. Just implement `IPageEvent` to any `Page` you want to add those methods and change your `NavigationPage` with `ExtNavPage`.

```
public class ExtNavPage : NavigationPage
{
    public ExtNavPage(Page page) : base(page)
    {
        this.AddNavigationEvent();
    }

    private void AddNavigationEvent()
    {
        Popped += (s, e) => NavEventHandle(e, true);
        PoppedToRoot += (s, e) => NavEventHandle(e, true);
        Pushed += (s, e) => NavEventHandle(e);
    }

    private void NavEventHandle(NavigationEventArgs e, bool isPop = false)
    {
        if (e.Page is IPageEvent pe) {
            if (isPop)
                pe.OnPopped();
            else
                pe.OnPushed();
        }
    }
}

public interface IPageEvent
{
    void OnPopped();
    void OnPushed();
}
```

Comment: I do know that onBackButton only work with the physical button. I also only run that app on android devices.

But I cannot use on PageDisappearing, because I need to still be subscribed when I push another page. But it run the PageDisappear when I push another page.

Comment: You need to extend the `NavigationPage` and do something when [Popped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.popped?view=xamarin-forms) or [Pushed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.pushed?view=xamarin-forms)